# MySQL Row Position Using ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get this to work. When I run the SELECT on the whole dataset I know that the record with cust_number shows up in position 6 (When Using ORDER BY) but this code returns position 37327 which is it's non ordered by position.

```
SELECT 
    x.position,
    x.cust_number,
    x.company,
    x.surname,
    x.first_name,
    x.title
FROM
    (SELECT 
        @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS position,
            c.cust_number,
            company,
            surname,
            first_name,
            title
    FROM
        1_customer_records c
    LEFT JOIN addresses a ON c.fk_addresses_id = a.id
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
    ORDER BY a.company , c.surname , c.first_name , c.title) x
WHERE
    x.cust_number = 43246;
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by this method?

Comment: Order by is on the result not the read(s), Please add table definitions as text.

Comment: I have a hybrid application that needs to know the edited position of the row so it can insert it in the array in the correct position. It's a Powerbasic application running on the users desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach using a temp table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE row_calc (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, fk INT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=MEMORY;

INSERT INTO row_calc(fk)
SELECT 
    cust_number
FROM
    1_customer_records c
        LEFT JOIN
    addresses a ON c.fk_addresses_id = a.id
    ORDER BY company,surname,first_name,title;

SELECT 
    id
FROM
    row_calc
WHERE
    fk = 43246 LIMIT 1;

DROP TABLE row_calc;
```